# Update object value in array React hooks way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How would I update a title of the specific id with hooks state setup. Here:

```
const NotesContainer = ({

}) => {
  const [notesDummyData, setNotesDummyData] = useState([
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'Sauna',
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      title: 'Finland',
    },
  ]);

  const onChangeItemName = (newTitle, oldTitle, itemId) => {

    //Update a new title here for id 7

  };
```

Could not find any example for setState hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map through the items and if the id is equal to the selected id you modify only the value:

```
 const onChangeItemName = (newTitle, oldTitle, itemId) => {
      setNotesDummyData(notesDummyData.map(x => {
           if(x.id !== itemId) return x
           return {...x, title: newTitle}
      }))
 }
```

Comment: Sweet, this made it happen.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting one of the answers to close the question

Comment: Love the approach of first returning all non matches. The stripped down "if else" is clean and raw, getting use to it now :) added ; after the returns ' return x; ' and ' return {..x, title: newTitle}; '

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map()`. For each item check if the `id` is equal to `itemId`. If it this, spread the item, and replace the `title`. If not, return the original item:

```
const onChangeItemName = (title, itemId) => {
  setNotesDummyData(notesDummyData.map(o => o.id === itemId ? ({
    ...o,
    title
  }) : o));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to update data using React Hook, but there is not working `setState()`, so there will be working `[notThis, thisOne(setNotesDummyDate)]` to update your data.

```
const [notesDummyData, setNotesDummyData] = useState([
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'Sauna',
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      title: 'Finland',
    },
  ]);
```

**Using React Hook method to Update data:**

```
const onChangeItemName = (newTitle, oldTitle, itemId) => {
       setNotesDummyDate = useState([
    {
      id: itemId, // Update
      title: newTitle,
    },
    {
      id: itemId, // Update
      title: newTitle,
    },
  ]);
 }
```

Still Curious, [study here about useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Cheer you!